# How to save a code in which I set up hide selection in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using visual studio 2013 with Fortran. My code is so long, so I use hide selection very often. However, when I turned off the visual studio and restart the program, hide selections I set up before disappear. This happens only to the main code that is the longest. Other subroutines keep hide selections I used. Do you have any good idea to solve this?